# How do I make objects not renderable in OpenGL Render / overlays disabled on Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, opengl

I have some mesh that i do not want to be visible when disabling the overlays button but they still do so, in Blender 2.79 checking the Render only box was enough but here it doesnt work like that. any ideas?

p.s., the object is not supposed to be rendered in render mode either

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can disable it in your collections, I generally put the meshes I don't want rendered in a separate collection, then when it comes time to render out I turn off that collection.  Hope this helps

Comment: its mostly for an armature, i got some panel with switches and the object helps to know what it does, but then i render in openGL they are still there so its a bit disappointing that i got random objects over my characters, back in 2.79 i had no problem doing such thing :c

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the answer you're looking for, but when you click on the funnel symbol in the outliner window, you can toggle the camera symbol, which shows you which objects will be rendered. You can toggle on/off by clicking on it just like you can with the visibility symbol.